# Deploy Springboot 1.5.22.RELEASE on Websphere 8.5.5.20

Tags: java, spring-boot, websphere, cxf, cxf-client

Hello I deploy spring boot app v1.5.22.RELEASE on Websphere 8.5.5.20 => OK

I use java version 1.8 and cxf-rt-transports-http and cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws v3.5.5

The problem is when i try to call the api I get this error :

```json
{
    "timestamp": 1688630892602,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "java.lang.ClassCastException",
    "message": "org.apache.axis2.jaxws.client.proxy.JAXWSProxyHandler incompatible with org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy",
    "path": "/Api/test1"
}
```

Please I need help after the good deployment of my application on WebSphere I try to make a call it doesn't work I get error 500 is someone else had this the same problem?

I have already used the class loader parent first on WebSphere it does not work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The ClassCastException message appears to indicate that you've got a mix of objects from Axis2 (the server's built-in web services provider) and CXF. Are you intending to use CXF only for web services, or are you relying on the server's implementation at all? Bringing your own web services implementation requires some additional configuration steps.